# Como testar métodos privados em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, testes-de-unidade

Como testar métodos privados utilizando o Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting e Moq

Minha classe de teste esta assim:

```
[TestClass]
public class ClasseDeTeste
{

    private  MinhaClasseComMetodosPrivados _minhaClasseComMetodosPrivados;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        ...inicialização de diversos repositórios 

        _minhaClasseComMetodosPrivados = new MinhaClasseComMetodosPrivados(parametros, ...);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestarFuncaoPrivadaXXX()
    {

       var result = _minhaClasseComMetodosPrivados.metodoPrivado(param1, param2, param3);

       Assert.AreEqual("retorno esperado ",result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas atende o que foi pedido? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: No caso acho que deve aceitar a do LINQ que é o que você queria saber de fato, a minha é complemento.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A princípio, não deveria testar. A ideia dos testes unitários é testar se a API pública está trabalhando da maneira esperada.

De qualquer forma, é possível usar a classe [`PrivateObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) do namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`. Ela foi criada justamente para esta finalidade.

Um exemplo de como usá-la:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestarFuncaoPrivadaXXX()
{       
    var target = new MinhaClasseComMetodosPrivados();       
    var obj = new PrivateObject(target);

    var result = obj.Invoke("MetodoPrivado");

    Assert.AreEqual("retorno esperado ",result);
}
```

Também é possível fazer com *reflection* "na mão". Algo como:

```
var target = new MinhaClasseComMetodosPrivados();
var methodInfo = typeof(MinhaClasseComMetodosPrivados).GetMethod("MetodoPrivado", 
                                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

object[] parametros = new [] { 1, "alguma string" }; // Só pra ilustrar
methodInfo.Invoke(target, parametros);
```

Também, obviamente, é possível criar uma classe *wrapper* e chamar os métodos privados através de métodos públicos, mas esta é uma abordagem bem sem vergonha.

Answer (score 9):

A resposta que deseja mesmo é a do Jéf Bueno, ainda que isso seja um erro (fica o alerta para todos). Porém fazer testes unitários em métodos privados é um erro conceitual.

Testes de unidade devem verificar se a API pública está sempre respondendo da maneira esperada. Métodos privados são detalhes de implementação e não fazem parte da API pública. Testá-los não faz sentido porque eles precisam ter a liberdade de poder resultar de forma diferente.

O máximo que pode ser interessante é ter uma verificação de invariância de estado do objeto entre a execução dos métodos privados. Mesmo isto é controverso porque há casos que não importa a invariância no meio do processamento privado.

Comment: Pode elaborar sobre "ter uma verificação de invariância de estado do objeto ...". Em quê isso(invariância de estado) pode afectar o cliente da API

Comment: @ramaral acha que vale aqui? parece ser um assunto tangencial e não o foco da pergunta. Não sei mesmo, se achar eu edito aqui, senão é melhor algo próprio pra isso.