# Verificação de invariância de estado do objeto entre a execução dos métodos privados

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, testes-de-unidade

Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210450/2541) à pergunta [Como testar métodos privados em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210440/2541) é referido

> O máximo que pode ser interessante é ter uma verificação de invariância de estado do objeto entre a execução dos métodos privados.

O que visa essa verificação e porque ela pode ser importante?

Comment: Vai vendo se preciso melhorar algo.

Comment: @bigown Está óptima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## DbC

Existe um paradigma secundário de desenvolvimento chamado *Design by Contract* (DbC). Ele pode ser usado em qualquer linguagem, mas algumas possuem sintaxe própria para facilitar. Ele é usado para dar mais confiabilidade ao código, para tornar mais explícito no código como o código deve interagir nas suas pontas.

Assim como se colocar tipo explícito de variáveis, em parâmetros, criando um contrato que deve ser cumprido, podemos colocar outras restrições de como os argumentos devem ser passados para um método.

Em geral usa-se pré-condições que verificam o que vem nos parâmetros de forma detalhada. O código não deve compilar ou emitir um erro de programação se algumas das condições foram violadas em sua chamada.

Um pouco menos usadas são as pós-condições que verificam se o resultado gerado pelo método atende alguma condição, ou seja ele responde o que se esperava.

Note que isso acaba fazendo parte do contrato do método. Em algumas linguagens formalmente fazendo parte da API, em outras apenas como uma verificação adicional.

Também pode-se usar asserções no meio do método para verificar no meio do algoritmo se tudo está ocorrendo corretamente.

Em alguns casos essas verificações podem ser desligadas em tempo de execução sem prejuízo. Isso dá mais performance e pode até reduzir o tamanho do código.

## Invariância

Outra verificação é se o estado do objeto está sempre dentro de determinadas condições estabelecidas. Ou seja, as variáveis do objeto devem conter valores de um jeito específico que mantenha o objeto sempre válido. Geralmente isso ocorre ao final de algum método que pode mudar o estado de algum membro da instância ou até do tipo.

Em outras palavras este estado não pode variar de forma inválida. Pelo menos enquanto o dado pode ser acessado publicamente.

Nada impede que o estado fique inválido durante a execução de um método ou até entre vários métodos privados, afinal métodos privados são detalhes de implementação. O que se faz internamente não importa, tudo é válido. Quando termina algo o estado precisa estar válido.

## Métodos privados

Em alguns casos pode-se querer impedir variância mesmo entre métodos privados. O texto fala disto.

Dependendo da linguagem fica até difícil garantir a invariância pública sem interferir na privada.

Em geral pré e pós-condições e invariância deveriam ser mais que suficientes para métodos privados, já que não fazem parte da API pública. Em alguns casos pode ser suficiente até para a API pública, dispensando completamente os testes, neste tipo.

## Conclusão

DbC é algo muito útil para aumentar a qualidade do código e evitar tanto teste, mantendo um pouco mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) já que a especificação está está no código.

Sem isso ou depende só de testes externos ou ficamos no *bumba-meu-boi*, você confia que você ou outra nunca fará uma alteração que comprometa o objeto ou resultado que ele deve fornecer.

Claro que saber o quanto deve usá-lo é quase uma arte. Alguma preferem o caminho simples de fazer em tudo, mesmo quando pode até ser mais problemático, ou o mais comum e mais simples ainda, não verificar nada, afinal ela é o Chuck Norris.

Queria ver mais isso em linguagens. [C# tem algo assim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas é meio gambiarra de biblioteca mais ferramenta externa (Visual Studio), então poucos usam. Mas querem por isso na linguagem do jeito certo.

[image: Code Contracts Visual Studio]

Foi até desligado em versões recentes.

- [Artigo Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
- [Wiki C2](http://wiki.c2.com/?DesignByContract)

[Exemplo de código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260837/221800) em [Spec#](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/spec/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é uma variação do C# desenvolvido pela Microsoft Research.

```
public static int BinarySearch(int[]! a, int key)
    requires forall{int i in (0: a.Length), int j in (i: a.Length); a[i] <= a[j]};
    ensures 0 <= result ==> a[result] == key;
    ensures result < 0 ==> forall{int i in (0: a.Length); a[i] != key};
 {
     int low = 0;
     int high = a.Length - 1;
     while (low <= high)
         invariant high+1 <= a.Length;
         invariant forall{int i in (0: low); a[i] != key};
         invariant forall{int i in (high+1: a.Length); a[i] != key};
     {
         int mid = (low + high) / 2;
         int midVal = a[mid];
         if (midVal < key) {
             low = mid + 1;
         } else if (key < midVal) {
             high = mid - 1;
         } else {
             return mid; // key found
         }
    }
    return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/BinarySearch.ss).

Note que existe invariância dentro do método, o que é me parece não ser a proposta inicial do DbC, mas que é algo que pode ser interessante no lugar da asserção.

Comment: Sobre invariância e acesso paralelo ao objeto, precisa usar uma trava para impedir que se tente ler o estado inválido intermediário?

Comment: Não domino o assunto suficientemente, mas o mecanismo está mais preocupado se o código está correto, não se o objeto realmente não é alterado. Por isso muito do código do DbC acaba sumindo do código final em execução. Não é um controle do objeto, é do código. Eu acho até que não importa o valor do objeto, importa o valor que foi alterado no estado naquela instância de execução. Certeza eu não posso te dar.

Comment: essas pós e pré condições todas me fizeram pensar bobeira =] de repente li como se fosse uma verificação runtime de produção, foi mal =D

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode ser, tem situações que isto é transformado em verificação de *runtime* podendo até mesmo lançar uma exceção. Mas depende de como o mecanismo foi implementado. Algumas coisas não tem como verificar em tempo de compilação. Se você não aceito um parâmetro receber 0 e chamar o método passando 0 ou algo que pode ser inferido com 0, ok, dá para saber. Mas e se o 0 surge de um cálculo usando um valor vindo do banco de dados, como saber em tempo de compilação? Não tem como. Em geral o bom *code coverage* ajuda.